# displaying file tree view of specific drive using java web

Tags: java, file, web, view, tree

As i searched, getting the file tree view for the specific path is quite straight forward and achievable by using swing packages on a desktop app. But is there any web application based on java to display it on browsers? Many of the application i found are written in PHP.
If you have any other option. Please suggest it to me. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Hi Akash, Did you manage to find an answer for this solution. If so can you please let me know?

Comment: I made simple custom tree view using jquery,css,java and struts2 framework with some help of my UX friend.

Comment: And i also used struts-json plugin to bring all the required file name and path to the web page. If you want i can post demo of some similar project on jsfiddle with static data.

Comment: Sure. As far as my research goes I am trying to fiddle with JQuery's jstree plugin but looking at your solution would definitely help me to achieve my result faster. Thanks

Comment: Check out this link. Hope it helps. http://jsfiddle.net/d9VEz/45/